# Efficient evaluation of spliced lists with a recurring argument

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos, expression-evaluation

I want to recur through a list of slot names of classes, the same slot names for two classes (`(current-trial *exp*)` & `(previous *exp*)` refer to instances of the same class). On each recursion, I want to evaluate the slot name so that the value of that slot of that instance may be got and set. The code below meets that expectation, but I worry about relying upon eval because it's slow and doesn't allow for lexical context (Graham, 1996). What would be alternative formulations that would be efficient and allow for lexical context?

```
(dolist (a '(letter number font color height))
  (eval 
   `(when (eq (,a (current-trial *exp*)) 
              (,a (previous *exp*)))
     (setf (,a (current-trial *exp*)) 
           (random-not-item 
            (,a (current-trial *exp*)) 
            (,a *exp*))))))
```

Comment: Why tag this with `recursion`? It's not even a function, how can it be recursive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since these are slot names, you can use `slot-value`:

```
(dolist (a '(letter number font color height))
  (when (eq (slot-value (current-trial *exp*) a) 
            (slot-value (previous *exp*) a))
    (setf (slot-value (current-trial *exp*) a) 
          (random-not-item 
           (slot-value (current-trial *exp*) a) 
           (slot-value *exp* a)))))
```